# Dynamically creating a new component based off another component's state

Tags: reactjs

First timer here on StackOverflow! I'm trying to emulate a terminal interface for one of my portfolio projects. The way I have envisioned the terminal is that each terminal box has a state object with a few key/value pairs. Ideally, when someone enters text into the terminal box input form, the input becomes disabled and a new terminal box is rendered on the screen with a dynamic response based upon the userInput text which has been saved in the state. Where I'm stuck:

1. Once userInput state has been updated, how do I get a new terminal box to render beneath the prior box on the screen?
2. Prior to rendering, how do I set the initial state of the newly-rendered terminal box back to default with the exception of the "output" which would be re-valued to an appropriate response that I set?
3. How do I access the state in the prior terminal box so I can "read" the userInput stored there so I can determine what the appropriate response to that input would be?

I've included copies of each of the components below:

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Terminal from "./components/Terminal";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Terminal />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Terminal.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import Falcon from "./Falcon";
import Messages from "./Alerts/Messages";

class Terminal extends Component {
  state = {
    output: Messages.intro,
    userInput: "",
    isComplete: false,
    isDisabled: "",
  };

  markComplete = () => {
    this.setState({
      isComplete: true,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (event, userInput) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      userInput: userInput,
      isDisabled: "disabled",
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Falcon
          output={this.state.output}
          markComplete={this.markComplete}
          isComplete={this.state.isComplete}
        />
        <p />
        <Form
          input={this.state.userInput}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          isComplete={this.state.isComplete}
          isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}
        />
        <p />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Terminal;
```

**Falcon.js** (***Note***: You'll see that there is a component "Typed" below - that is part of Matt Boldt's Typed.js (of which react-typed is an offshoot package) package which I'm using to simulate typing.)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Typed from 'react-typed'

class Falcon extends Component {
  state = {
    output: this.props.output,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Typed
          strings={[this.state.output]}
          typeSpeed={40}
          onComplete={(self) => {
            self.cursor.remove();
            this.props.markComplete();
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Falcon;
```

**Form.js**

```js
import React from "react";

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: this.props.input,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        style={{
          display: this.props.isComplete === false ? "none" : "",
        }}
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          this.props.onSubmit(event, this.state.input);
        }}
      >
        {"> "}
        <input
          ref={(input) => input && input.focus()}
          type="text"
          disabled={this.props.isDisabled}
          style={{
            border: "none",
            outline: "none",
            backgroundColor: "#FFF",
            color: "#000",
          }}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={(event) => this.setState({ input: event.target.value })}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Any insight or guidance you can offer would be much appreciated! Thank you for helping this "first-timer" out!

Comment: If you want multiple `Terminal` instances then you will need some state in `App` to manage them. Store each terminal's state object in an array there and map over them in the render function of `App`. Then when you submit one, you can read the data from all the previous ones and decide what the next one should look like before adding it to the array.

Comment: @lawrence-witt - Thank you for the suggestion. I believe that's where I have to go next but I'm struggling with totally understanding how to accomplish that. I've created a [code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/falcon-front-end-10vpw?file=/src/components/Terminal.js:286-465) that shows where I'm presently at. Do you have any suggestions on how I might move forward?

Comment: Sandbox seems broken unfortunately. All the files are empty.

Comment: @lawrence-witt - I'm so sorry! I guess I didn't save it (I'm not used to code sandbox). The link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falcon-front-end-10vpw?file=/src/App.js). My apologies once again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I made a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-merkle-hrc4i?file=/src/components/Terminal.js) with a few changes.

When developing React applications, it's a good practice to model the UI (the DOM elements) as a function of your internal state. You update the state and the UI changes automatically, it *reacts* to updates.

That said, you probably want to consider using the form only for the actual input element at the bottom of the terminal. The "past buffer" is just an array that only increases its content with user input and program output. Another good practice (actually a commandment!) is to never mutate the state. So, if you want to update the array, you create a new one from scratch, as in:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  conversation: [
    ...state.conversation, // we spread the previous state into the new one
    { text: state.userInput, id: faker.random.uuid(), type: "input" } // the last element is appended
  ]
}));}
```

Notice how setState (in class components) just schedules an update for the fields that you used. As your app scales, you will probably want to limit the length of this array.

The terminal component could be like:

```
class Terminal extends Component {
  state = {
    output: "Messages.intro",
    userInput: "",
    isComplete: false,
    isDisabled: "",
    conversation: [] // couldn't think of a nice name :(
  };

  markComplete = () => {
    this.setState({
      isComplete: true
    });
  };

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ userInput: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState((state) => ({
      userInput: "",
      conversation: [
        ...state.conversation,
        { text: state.userInput, id: faker.random.uuid(), type: "input" }
      ]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { conversation, userInput, output, isComplete } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Falcon
          output={output}
          markComplete={this.markComplete}
          isComplete={isComplete}
        />

        <p />

        // This is not really a form. Should be changed to another readonly element
        {conversation.map((item, index) => (
          <Form
            key={item.id}
            input={item.text}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            isComplete={isComplete}
            isDisabled
          />
        ))}

        <p />

        <Form
          input={userInput}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
          isComplete={isComplete}
          isDisabled={false}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <p />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you created state as a mirror of the props. Only do that if you want them to be different at some point. Otherwise, use only props.

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested but they gave me an error re: controlled vs. uncontrolled components. I made a couple of the changes you suggested and realized that I needed to change the component structure somewhat (App -> Terminal -> InputOutput -> Falcon & Form) to better hold state. I'm presently struggling with updating the state in Terminal - you can see the [code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falcon-front-end-10vpw?file=/src/components/Terminal.js:286-465). Do you have any advice on how to move forward?

Comment: This linked CodeSandbox is empty.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I guess I didn't save it (I'm not used to code sandbox). The link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falcon-front-end-10vpw?file=/src/App.js). My apologies once again.